# If Dynamic URL is specific, do this?

Tags: php, url, dynamic

I have this code being used on my website

```
if( isset($_GET['gw'] )){
  //this is some content
}
```

So whenever my url is something like this

```
http://mywebsite.com/?gw=hello
```

the content inside that div will appear. It works very well, but now what I want to do is have different content for a specific string. Something like this

```
if (gw=hello) { 
 // content here
} else if (gw=goodbye) {
 // content here
} else {
 //content here
}
```

I know that is not the code, but does anyone know a way I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pretty much there!

```
if(isset($_GET['gw'])) {

     if($_GET['gw'] == "hello") {

     }
     else if ($_GET['gw'] == "goodbye") {

     }
     else {

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to use a [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement, so you can easily expand on the conditions in the future.

```
switch (isset($_GET['gw']) ? $_GET['gw'] : '')
{
    case "hello":
      // do something here
      break;

    case "goodbye":
      // do something here
      break;

    default:
      // default action if nothing above matches
      break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this as well! I will probably be using it sometime!